# Lua Script coroutine

Tags: multithreading, lua, coroutine

Hi need some help on my lua script. I have a script here that will run a server like application (infinite loop). Problem here is it doesn't execute the second coroutine.

Could you tell me whats wrong Thank you.

```
function startServer()
    print( "...Running server" )
    --run a server like application infinite loop
    os.execute( "server.exe" ) 
end
function continue()
    print("continue")
end

co = coroutine.create( startServer() )
co1 = coroutine.create( continue() )
```

Comment: If you want to know more about multi tasking in Lua, the you can read my answer to a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943785/thread-priorities-in-lua/15944052#15944052

Comment: Start with reading [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted, there are several issues with the script that prevent you from getting what you want:

- `os.execute("...")` is blocked until the command is completed and in your case it doesn't complete (as it runs an infinite loop). **Solution:** you need to detach that process from yours by using something like `io.popen()` instead of `os.execute()`
- `co = coroutine.create( startServer() )` doesn't create a coroutine in your case. `coroutine.create` call accepts a function reference and you pass it the result of `startServer` call, which is `nil`. **Solution:** use `co = coroutine.create( startServer )` (note that parenthesis are dropped, so it's not a function call anymore).
- You are not yielding from your coroutines; if you want several coroutines to work together, they need to be cooperating by giving control to each other when appropriate. That's what `yield` command is for and that's why it's called [non-preemptive multithreading](http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html). **Solution:** you need to use a combination of `resume` and `yield` calls after you `create` your coroutine.
- `startServer` doesn't need to be a coroutine as you are not giving control back to it; its only purpose is to start the server.

In your case, the solution may not even need coroutines as all you need to do is: (1) start the server and let it detach from your process (for example, using `popen`) and (2) work with your process using whatever communication protocol it requires (pipes, sockets, etc.).

There are more complex and complete solutions (like [LuaLanes](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes)) and also several good descriptions on creating [simple coroutine dispatchers](http://williamaadams.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/lua-coroutines-getting-started/).

Answer (score 7):

Lua have cooperative multithreading. Threads are not swtiched automatically, but must `yield` to others. When one thread is running, every other thread is waiting for it to finish or yield. Your first thread in this example seems to run `server.exe`, which, I assume, never finishes until interrupted. Thus second thread never gets its turn to run.

You also run threads wrong. In your example you're not running any threads at all. You execute function and then would try to create coroutine with its output, which naturally would fail. But since you never get back from `server.exe` you didn't notice this problem yet. Remove those brackets after `startServer` and `continue` to fix it.

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick response, how can I yield it to others?

Comment: Hi, I think I get it now. so it must wait for the server to stop then my second script will run?. Is there other way to run both scripts at the same time?

Comment: Yes. `server.exe` should deattach from console to allow `os.execute` to return. Alternatively use Windows's means to run it in separate window, i.e. `os.execute('cmd /c start "server" server.exe')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your coroutine is not yielding